# GWT 2.7.0: ListBox rendered complete event

Tags: java, gwt

When a GWT ListBox completes to render its list does it send an event? Or is there a callback after the list is initialized? When I try to programmatically set a value it throws a null reference exception because the value is not yet in the list.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about your particular case, but from what you say, sometimes one needs to defer some code until after the browser redraws the page and/or pending events are processed.

For this purpose `Schedule.scheduleDeferred()` can be used:

```
    Scheduler.get().scheduleDeferred( () -> {
        // Deferred code here
        ...
    });
```